# Неравенство строки-переменной и константы

Tags: ruby, ldap

Использую библиотеку `net/ldap`.
Без проблем выполняются все действия до фрагмента:

```
ldap.search( :base => treebase, :filter => filter ) do |entry| puts
"DN: #{entry.dn}"
#  entry.homedirectory.each do |en|
#  entry.each do |en|  entry.each do |attribute, values|

         if attribute == "mail"

                puts "  #{attribute}:"
                values.each do |value|
                        puts "      --->#{value}"
                end
         end
  end
end
```

В списке `ldap` атрибутов точно есть с именем `mail`, однако условие `if attribute == "mail"` никогда не исполняется. И блок внутри не исполняется, однако
если условия убрать печатаются все атрибуты (включая mail) и их значения.

Пытался сравнивать символы атрибута `mail` "посимвольно" c `"m"` `"a"` `"i"` `"l"` - 
выдается истина.

Comment: а какой именно объект находится в **attribute**? вы уверены, что там именно строка?

Comment: Это всплыло бы мгновенно, если бы вы делали `p attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего в **attribute** находиться **symbol**. При выводе на печать он выглядит как строка, но при этом не равен строке.

Попробуйте вот так

```
if attribute.to_s == "mail"
```